# How to get only records with ID's specified, IN-Clause in LINQ

Tags: linq, visual-studio

I am using VS 2013
Language Vb

I want to write a Linq query like

```
select * from table where id in (1,2,3)
```

How can I write this query using Linq?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim ids As Int32() = { 1, 2, 3 }
Dim query = From obj In db.Table
            Where ids.Contains(obj.id)
```